# Polymer: observing path changes and deep path observation in declared properties

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I'm using `polymer` (v1.1.5) with `webcomponentsjs` (v0.7.14) in Chrome (v45).

Unless I'm missing something, it looks like the Polymer code examples provided in the "Declared properties" section, under  "[Observing path changes](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#observing-path-changes)"  and  "[Deep path observation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#deep-observation)" are not working.

#### Observing path changes

```
Polymer({
  is: 'x-custom',
  properties: {
    user: Object
  },
  observers: [
    'userManagerChanged(user.manager)'
  ],
  userManagerChanged: function(user) {
    console.log('new manager name is ' + user.name);
  }
});
```

This is the result:

```
document.querySelector('x-custom').user // -> 'undefined'
```

I tried to initialize it differently:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'x-custom',
  properties: {
    user: {
      type: Object,
      value: function () {
        return {};
      }
    }
  },
  observers: [
    'userManagerChanged(user.manager)'
  ],
  userManagerChanged: function(user) {
    console.log('new manager name is ' + user.name);
  }
});
```

Now:

```
// -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

And even like this:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'x-custom',
  properties: {
    user: {
      type: Object,
      value: function () {
        return {manager: 'John'};
      }
    }
  },
  observers: [
    'userManagerChanged(user.manager)'
  ],
  userManagerChanged: function(user) {
    console.log('new manager name is ' + user.name);
  }
});
```

Result:

```
// -> new manager name is undefined
document.querySelector('x-custom').user.manager // -> "John"
document.querySelector('x-custom').user.manager = 'Paul' // -> "Paul"
// document.querySelector('x-custom').user.manager // -> "Paul"
// The property value has been updated, but the change has not been observed and no callback has been called
```

The same holds true for the code examples in **"Deep path observation"**.

Does anyone know how to fix this and get it working properly? Thanks!

Comment: You are assigning a name into user.manager. That is what is going to be passed on to the function. Not the user object itself. your function should be  userManagerChanged: function(managerName) {console.log('new manager name is ' + managerName);  }

Comment: I think you should check the [deep path observation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#deep-observation) docs again, there are several parts different in the example code compared to what you're posting here (like the observers array being defined as `['userManagerChanged(user.manager.*)']` instead of `['userManagerChanged(user.manager)']`)

Comment: @Alan, as I mentioned in bold at the top the example I posted is from "[Observing path changes](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#observing-path-changes)" docs, but anyways the same concept applies to "Deep path observation".

Comment: @Srik this code is not mine: is from official Polymer docs, check the links.

Comment: But you are assigning a string to the manager. The e.g. code assumes it to be an object which has 'name' property. If you post a jsbin then your issue will be more clear.

Comment: @Srik I guess the Polymer team should fix their docs then :)

Comment: I agree that they could give better e.g. The given e.g. is not incorrect. user.manager can be considered as another user object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this.set or this.notifyPath while changing path value such that observers are notified. Please read the below for more details.

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path

Below jsbin demonstrates observers for object path:

http://jsbin.com/qupoja/4/edit?html,output

In your case the below might work

```
document.querySelector('x-custom').set('user.manager','Paul')
```

In addition to that, as I mentioned in the comments, you have to modify the user manager observer to accept string as parameter rather than user object.

```
userManagerChanged: function(managerName) {
  console.log('new manager name is ' + managerName);
}
```